# Problems reassigning a variable value while converting a for loop into a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach

I am trying to convert a loop from a for loop into a forEach loop that iterates over an array. The aim of the loop is that it will find the largest number in an array and return the largest number.

It works when I try to do it as a for loop but I can't seem to do it as a forEach loop. Is it possible, if so then how? Otherwise why can't it be done?

Here is the for loop, **this works as I want it to**

```
 function getBig(x){
 var largeNumber = 0;
 var argue = x;
 for(i = 0; i < argue.length; i++){
    if(argue[i] > largeNumber){
            var largeNumber = argue[i];

        }
 }
 console.log(largeNumber);
 };
```

Here is the forEach

```
 function getBig(x){
    var largeNumber = 0;
    var argue = x;
    argue.forEach(function(theNumber){
        if(theNumber > largeNumber){
            var largeNumber = theNumber;
        }
    })
    console.log(largeNumber);
  };
```

The trouble I seem to have is changing the value of a variable in the forEach. How can I change it?

Comment: it's to do with the scope of `var largeNumber = argue[i];` - don't use `var` inside the forEach for that variable name, and it'll use the outerscoped one instead

Comment: Hey Jaromanda, thank you for the tip! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  **for**, you are creating **largeNumber** as a global variable by declaring it with **var** in global context only. So when you access **largeNumber** again after the loop, it gives you correct value.

In **forEach**, you are creating **largeNumber** using **var** in a function Which is limited to the function’s scope.

For **forEach**, remove **var** declaration, it will work fine:

> largeNumber = theNumber

.

Answer (score 1):

`var`s are hoisted and have function scope, rather than block scope. To the interpreter, your original code looks something like this:

```
function getBig(x){
  var largeNumber;
  largeNumber = 0;
  var argue = x;
  for(i = 0; i < argue.length; i++){
    if(argue[i] > largeNumber){
      largeNumber = argue[i];

    }
  }
  console.log(largeNumber);
};
```

In your `forEach`, the `largeNumber` is hoisted to the top of the *nearest function*, which is not the same as the `getBig` function. Let's call it `largeNumber2` for clarity - to the interpreter, it looks like this:

```
function getBig(x){
  var largeNumber = 0;
  var argue = x;
  argue.forEach(function(theNumber){
    var largeNumber2;
    if(theNumber > largeNumber2){
      largeNumber2 = theNumber;
    }
  })
  console.log(largeNumber);
};
```

It's a separate variable, bound to the inside of the `forEach`, and not visible outside. Try assigning it to the `largeNumber` in the outer scope instead by not using `var` in the inner function:

```js
function getBig(x){
  var largeNumber = 0;
  var argue = x;
  argue.forEach(function(theNumber){
    if(theNumber > largeNumber){
      largeNumber = theNumber;
    }
  })
  console.log(largeNumber);
}
getBig([2, 3, 4, 1, 2]);
```

Also note that functions should not have semicolons after their final bracket. Your function could be simplified to:

```js
const getBig = arr => console.log(Math.max(...arr));
getBig([2, 3, 4, 1, 2]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, the explanation is much appreciated.